# Combine 2 MySQL SELECTs in one line

Tags: mysql, select

How write this 2 `SELECT` on one line. I need get 2 queries. The first query is this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank FROM `rang_info` WHERE `player_kills` > (SELECT `player_kills` FROM `rang_info` WHERE `player_name` = '%s')
```

The second query is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rang_info`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single row, then something like below should work

```
SELECT SUM(rank) AS rank, SUM(total) AS total 
FROM
(SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank, 0 AS total FROM `rang_info` 
WHERE `player_kills` > (SELECT `player_kills` FROM `rang_info` WHERE `player_name` = '%s')
UNION
SELECT 0 AS rank, COUNT(*) AS total FROM `rang_info`) AS temptable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). Should work:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank FROM `rang_info` WHERE `player_kills` > (SELECT `player_kills` FROM `rang_info` WHERE `player_name` = '%s')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rang_info`
```